Change Datetime Frequency in a df Column - Pandas
If I have df with a column like 'B' below, but I want to change the frequency of the column B, to 1 business day instead of 3 business days, so that the output df will have 7 entries, instead of 3; how to use .offsets() or Dateoffset() to do this please?
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'A': np.random.randint(0, 20, size = 3), 
    'B': pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods = 3, freq = '3B')
}
)
    
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('Int64')


Option 1
df.set_index + df.asfreq + df.reset_index + df.loc to re-order. (This will get you 7 business days, because of initial min and max for column 'B'.)
out = df.set_index('B').asfreq('1B').reset_index().loc[:, [*'AB']]

Output:
# with `np.random.seed(0)` for reproducibility

      A          B
0    12 2010-01-01
1  <NA> 2010-01-04
2  <NA> 2010-01-05
3    15 2010-01-06
4  <NA> 2010-01-07
5  <NA> 2010-01-08
6     0 2010-01-11

Option 2
pd.date_range + df.reindex + df.rename_axis + reset_index + df.loc.
reindex = pd.date_range(df['B'].min(), periods=7, freq='1B')

out2 = (
    df.set_index('B')
    .reindex(reindex)
    .rename_axis('B')
    .reset_index().loc[:, [*'AB']]
    )

Option 3
df.merge
out3 = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'B': reindex}), on='B', how='right')

Option 4
df.resample + resample.asfreq (More useful if you want to fill_value or instead use resample.interpolate.)
out4 = df.set_index('B').resample('1B').asfreq().reset_index().loc[:, [*'AB']]

Equality check:
dfs = [out, out2, out3, out4]
all(df.equals(dfs[0]) for df in dfs)

# True


Thank you :-)
But one final question please (Sorry, I'm still studying datetime in pandas):

So can we say that in order to change the datetime freq for a pandas' df col, it'd be easier to change the col to an index, then reset the index again, correct?
When I set the col 'B' as an index, I  was very easily able to change it using:
df = df.asfreq('B')


Yes, that's correct. In general, when working with time series data, it's convenient to use a datetime index. This makes filtering, slicing, etc. much easier. See Time series / date functionality and How to handle time series data with ease, specifically Datetime as index.

One method without using the index and by linearly interpolating on the additional days:
display(df)


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': None, 
    'B': pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods = 7, freq = '1B') })

dico = {b:a for (a, b) in zip(df["A"], df["B"])}

df2["A"] = df2.apply(lambda row: dico.get(row["B"], np.nan) , axis=1).interpolate()
display(df2)


